# Openpyxl creates empty chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I've been trying to make an Excel file to represent some data that I get from a python program using Openpyxl.

I can get the data into the file easily but I'm having trouble creating graphs.

A graph appears at the location that I want but it has no data in it.

The label names are at B19-F19 and the actual data is at B20-F20.

Here's my code:

```py
chart = BarChart()
chart.type = "col"
chart.style = 10
labels = Reference(ws, min_row=2, max_row=6, min_col=19)
data = Reference(ws, min_row=2, max_row=6, min_col=20)
chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(labels)
chart.shape = 4
ws.add_chart(chart, "O2")
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: How are you viewing the resulting file?

Comment: Using LibreOffice. I'm not sure if there's a better way of doing it seeing as I'm working on Linux

Comment: The Excel file? I can share it with you if that would help?

Answer (score 0):

Probably is a little late , but I give you an example . If you have your data controlled then just replace the variable row by your data :

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Series, Reference

wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()

#If you have controlled the data , rows replace by your data
rows = [
    ('Number', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2'),
    (2, 10, 30),
    (3, 40, 60),
    (4, 50, 70),
    (5, 20, 10),
    (6, 10, 40),
    (7, 50, 30),
]

for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)


chart = BarChart()
chart.type = "col"
chart.style = 10
# Add X and Y
chart.y_axis.title = 'Test'
chart.x_axis.title = 'length'

data = Reference(ws, min_row=1, max_row=7, min_col=2,max_col=3)
labels = Reference(ws, min_row=2, max_row=7, min_col=1)

chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(labels)
chart.shape = 4
ws.add_chart(chart, "A10")
wb.save("bar.xlsx")
```

the result is some like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It’s blank because you cell values are text and not numbers. I had this same issue!